# Visual Studio Game Controller

Tags: visual-studio-2010, events, mouse

I'm making a program to improve your gaming skills, so its not a hacking program!

Now, I'm stuck on one thing, I need sort of a keylogger, that will logg what you do, For example, when you press space, it has to put Jumped in a Rich Text Box.
When you left mouse click, it has to add Shots Fired to the Rich Text Box, and then, when right mousebutton is clicked, add Aiming Down Sights, but when its released it should also add something like Stopped Aiming Down Sights.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Arrow Key - KeyDown for the whole window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378865/detect-arrow-key-keydown-for-the-whole-window)

Comment: I need to capture it out when the form is in the background, with a game running in front of it, so not really a duplicate

Comment: How exactly do you expect the user to enter a space in the foreground app if that's supposed to work?  Youneedtothinkthisthroughabit.Type"RegisterHotKey"intheSearchboxattheupperrightofthispage.

Comment: Hello, i just want, if the user presses space, it should say a text in the richtextbox

Answer (score 0):

I found out i had to ad this code, but still, i haven't foun the spacebar yet

```
 If Chr(i) = "(" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[Arrow Down]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "%" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[Arrow Left]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "'" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[Arrow Right]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "&" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[Arrow up]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[mouse click left]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[mouse click right]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[backspace]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "." Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[delete]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[shift]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = " " Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "[tab]"
ElseIf Chr(i) = "¾" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "."
ElseIf Chr(i) = "¼" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & ","
ElseIf Chr(i) = "¿" Then
txtkeys.Text = txtkeys.Text & "/"
```