# KeyDown event not firing?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keydown, onkeydown

When coding a small game, I encountered a problem; my form's `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events don't fire at all.

This is the form's code:

```
public class GameForm : Form
{
    private ControllableBlock player;

    public GameForm()
    {
        KeyDown += Game_KeyDown;
        KeyUp += Game_KeyUp;

        player = new ControllableBlock();
        Controls.Add(player);
    }

    private void Game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        player.ReactToKey(e.KeyCode);
    }

    private void Game_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        player.ReactToKey(e.KeyCode);
    }
}
```

There's a lot more going on, but I only pasted the relevant code.

I've already tried setting `this.KeyPreview = true;` and calling `this.Focus();`, neither works.
The problem is not in `ReactToKey()` method, I've already set a breakpoint there and the event is never fired.

---

**Edit:** After some tests I've come to a conclusion that the problem is within my `ControllableBlock`.
Yet, I have no idea why, but I'm working on it.
If I comment out everything that's related to the `player`, the events start firing.

---

**Edit 2:** Seems like the problem is me inheriting my `ControllableBlock` from `Control`.
If I inherit it from `Panel`, it works fine.
*Why is this?
Can't I fire an event if I inherit from control?*
The `ControllableBlock` class is empty for now, so it doesn't even do anything other than inherits from `Control`.

---

**Edit 3:** Now that I've started a bounty, I'd like to clarify that I'm not looking for a solution on how to make the events fire, I'm looking for a reason on why they don't fire if I inherit from `Control`.

Comment: `player.Obstacles.Add(obstacle);` what happens here? I tried to reproduce your issue but all eventhandlers with `this.KeyPreview = true` work well (except arrow keys - will think about workaround here). Without this line, indeed no events are fired

Comment: I don't know why yours doesn't work but mine works. Just create a new control, when the form is shown, focus that control like this `Shown += (s,e) => { myControl.Focus(); };` and then press some key down, it does work. If you want to focus your control by mouse clicking, I think it is not focused that way and you thought it didn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce a similar issue (which is hopefully related..)

Explanation:

- Controls which return `CanSelect==true` are selectable for keyboard input
- A blank descendent of `Control()` is selectable, one of `Panel()` is not
- The first selectable control added to a form will get selected
- A selected control will steal keyboard events from its parents by default
- Certain keys used for navigation within a window require extra steps to be handleable

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171535.aspx) for a good overview of how windows keyboard input works.

Code to reproduce it:

```
public class GameForm : Form
{
    public GameForm()
    {
        this.KeyDown += Game_KeyDown;
        var tests = new List<Control[]>() { 
            new[] { new Panel() },
            new[] { new Panel(), new Panel() },
            new[] { new Control() },
            new[] { new Control(), new Panel() },
            new[] { new Panel(), new Control() }
        };
        // When test index 2 to 4 used, keyboard input does not reach form level
        Controls.AddRange(tests[0]);            
        // When uncommented, ensures all keyboard input reaches form level
        /*this.KeyPreview = true;              
        // Additional plumbing required along with KeyPreview to allow arrow and other reserved keys
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            control.PreviewKeyDown += control_PreviewKeyDown;
        }*/
    }
    void control_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
    private void Game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // breakpoint here
        Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer may be interesting, but it is not any help at all to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If your events should be application-wide try to set property `KeyPreview` to `true` - it will allow you to fire respective events regardless of focused control.

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Otherwise you should attach these events directly to control that will process them.

**Edit:**

I removed `InitializeComponent();` from my form and got behaviour identical to yours.

After implementing solution provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378865/detect-arrow-key-keydown-for-the-whole-window) question all events started to qork perfectly.
Copy code snippet here:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == Keys.Left) {
            // Do your staff for Left Key here

            return true;
        }
        // you need to add if condition to every direction you want to handle
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: He is doing it right. You've just done it the old pre-.Net 2 way.

Comment: this is how VS2012 generates them with .Net 4.5... learned smth new myself today, thanks. Edited answer to highlight another possible option

Comment: @Nogard Unfortunately, that I already mentioned in my main post. Read the latest edits for additional information.

Comment: @Nogard Yeah I've already found that, but I would rather not override the ProcessCmdKey. I'm more curious on why does my program not work if I inherit my class from `Control`, but it does work if I inherit it from `Panel`.

Comment: **You really *should* be overriding `ProcessCmdKey`.** The `KeyPreview` property is only there for backwards compatibility with VB 6. You need it because `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` otherwise apply only when the control has the focus, and the form itself will never have the focus if it has focusable children. `ProcessCmdKey` solves that problem. @Markus

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah I know that nowadays, didn't back then. My project no longer even exists, I'm just curious on why inheriting from `Control` disables the key events but inheriting from `Panel` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the handler setup to the Form_Load event rather than the constructor. Should there not be a call to `Initialize()` in the constructor? I wouldn't particularly recommend removing it

If `ControllableBlock` inherits from Panel, it will have more event hookups and better UI interaction setup than a base Control object.

Comment: Initialize what? This is all hand coded and I didn't use the designer at all. Everything that needs to be initialized, is initialized in the constructor. `Form_Load` event didn't help either. It did fire tho, so the problem is within the keyevents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your control selectable before it can receive the focus.

Try adding the following to your constructor:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
```

And ensure that you give your form focus after it has been displayed. Or, override OnMouseDown() and call this.Focus() in it.