# Cancel PreviewKeyDown

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events

When the typing cursor is in a textbox I want catch the Arrow keys, 
do some treatment then prevent this event for being handled by the input.

In `KeyPress` event we have `KeyPressEventArgs` that we can put `e.Handled=false;` 
to deal with. 
But Arrows keys don't trig `KeyPress` event.

I have tried with `e.IsInputKey = true;` then  int `KeyDown` Event as MS says.

[Msdn Control.PreviewKeyDown Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

But seems `e.Handled=false;` doesn't work neither.

Here is my current code

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{    
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
                e.IsInputKey = true;               
}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{                         
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
     {
            // some other treatment [...]
        e.Handled = false;               
     }
}
```

[image]

I want to change the default pressing arrow behaviour in TextBox which moves the cursor. I don't want to the typing cursor between "r" and "l" (above) could be able to move.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It's really hard to tell. Is it that arrow keys don't fire `KeyPress`? Is it that you want to prevent further event handling after your own method?

Comment: shouldn't it be `e.Handled=true`?

Comment: sorry I've just edited my question, you're right it was not clear enought

Comment: And what exactly didn't work with `e.IsInputKey = true` in the `PreviewKeyDown`? It would help if you can show some code of what you've tried.

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378865/detect-arrow-key-keydown-for-the-whole-window and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event ?

Comment: @Dave you're right I didn't read well, with handled = true it work. sorry guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is vague, it doesn't describe the *specific* cursor keys that need to act differently.  It matters, TextBox already turns the Right and Left cursor keys into input keys.  So that they won't be used for navigation between controls.  You only need PreviewKeyDown if you want to intercept the Up/Down cursor keys.  Implement behavior in the KeyDown event handler.

Intention is vague as well, I'll just give a very silly example that swaps the direction of the cursor keys:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        var box = (TextBox)sender;
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left) {
            if (box.SelectionStart < box.Text.Length)
                box.SelectionStart++;
            e.Handled = true;
        } else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right) {
            if (box.SelectionStart > 0)
                box.SelectionStart--;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Note how `e.Handled` must be set to *true* to ensure that the keystroke isn't passed on to the control.

Comment: The main point for the OP being to set `e.Handled = true` and not false.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes, I mixed e.handled =true behaviour with handled = false, I tough the default value of handled was false.

Comment: And As you said no Preview is needed :-(