# Sometimes keys up down are not working on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Sometimes keys **up down** are not working on `DataGridView`.

I have no clue why and especially it is weird because there is no code assigned to key's events of `DataGridView`...

> SelectionMode is FullRowSelect
>
> Multiselect is False

This code dos not help...

```
     private void dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, reviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
            {
                switch (e.KeyCode)
                {
                    case Keys.Down:
                        e.IsInputKey = true;
                        break;
                    case Keys.Up:
                        e.IsInputKey = true;
                        break;
                }
            }

  private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)
            {

                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            {

                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Any clue?

P.S.

It seems like the  `SelectionChanged` method does some hard work... So When I disable it eberything is fine.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some hard work
}
```

So the quesion is how to optimize it.

I assume to use Timer so when user stops select arrows keys 1 second later
code of the `SelectionChanged` method should be executed.

Any clue about the best way to do it?

Comment: use PreviewKeyUp / PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: @MitraM Would u mind to explain why do I have to use them and how it should be done?

Comment: Please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673415/cancel-previewkeydown) .

Comment: @MitraM Sorry, you code does not help. I just updated my answers.

Comment: Which keys are ignored ? While editing cell or not ?

Comment: @Bioukh Hey... There is no editing at all. I have got a simple populated DataGRidView and I want to navigate using Arrows Up & Down. So sometimes I can got to the couple of next rows and then it stops to move in both directions. I have no clue why it happens.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is your `DataGridView` in edit mode ?  If so, maybe the key events are already handled by the edited cell. Try to set your `DataGridView` in `ReadOnly` mode to see if it comes from this.

Comment: @Bioukh Hi!  It is in RedOnly mode....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow during of executing `SelectionChanged` the grid losts its focus.
And probably it is happening because of the creation and inserting **User Controls** on fly.

So I did three adjustments and now it is fine!

```
 bool canDoHardWork = true;
 private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (canDoHardWork)
            {
                int interval = 2000; // Just 2 seconds
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    canDoHardWork= false;
                    Thread.Sleep(interval);
                    this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {                         
                        PopulateTabs(); // Very hard work
                        dataGridView1.Focus();
                        canDoHardWork= true;
                    }), null);

                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that when you `PopulateTabs()` you then have to set the Focus back to the `DataGridView` again. This was your problem with the Up and Down arrow keys. The events for the keys were being caught by your custom control(s). As for the very hard work (PopulateTabs), I notice you're using asynchronous threading with the `TPL`. Have you thought of doing away with the sleep interval as it seems redundant just set your DoesHardWork variable and change the focus to the `DataGridView` outside the Task. The reason it is working the way it does at the moment is that the `SelectionChanged` event fires twice the first time it "DoesHardWork" the second time it falls through as DoesHardWork is still false while it is processing the `PopulateTabs()`. A more elegant solution would be to set the CellValue/RowValue/Control which is generated by `PopulateTabs()` to the Object you would return from PopulateTabs() using `IAsyncResult`.

Something Like This :

```
bool canDoHardWork = true;

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (canDoHardWork)
   {
    IAsyncResult result;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
       canDoHardWork = false;
       result = this.BeginInvoke((Func<Button>)(() =>
       {                         
           canDoHardWork = true;
           return PopulateTabs(); // Very hard work
       }), null);
       this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add((Button)this.EndInvoke(result));
       dataGridView1.Focus();
    });
   }
}
```

There's no need to wait for the thread to complete as when it does it will just add the custom control to the DataGridView and return the control to the main thread. The thread sleep in your example would occur on the asynchronous thread and is as such redundant. In this example the heavy lifting is performed on another thread leaving the main thread free to continue accepting input. Have to put the focus for the DataGridView after the addition of the control or the focus won't change when it needs to.

Comment: Your comment looks great for me. Would you mind to add a code example into so I can test it and probably mark you answer as a correct, please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its to late but in my problem, using `e.Handled = true` is the problem.
Put wisely where the command should placed for.

Example :
If on event Key Down, and every Key Enter that user press you want the selected row dont move down and you use the event `e.Handled`. Put that command like this :

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
   e.Handled = true;
   //Do the command
}
```

Dont use outside the if condition because it will freeze the selected row no matther what key that user press.

In your case, using `e.Handled` inside Up and down Key Press event just makes it worst, cause every time user press the key, the selected row wont move Up or Down cause with the command `e.Handled`, you command the program to not move the cursor from the selected row.

Sorry for my bad english...