# Disabling/enabling TAB key (NOT all control keys) within a single form coding

Tags: vb.net

I have an input form written using textboxes and comboboxes where the RETURN
key is used to pass focus to the the next object.  I wish to disable the TAB key programatically in this form when loading, and re-enable it when closing the form.
Is this possible?  I'm using Visual Basic 2017 and a hobbyist rather than a
professional developer.
If possible any pointers appreciated.

Regards DayW

Comment: Add a handler on the form itself to preview keydown event and consume the unwanted key.  That way it will not be propagate to controls within the form.  You don't need to remove when your form closed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379340/17034